# Sorting Nested Lists in R with Python Semantics

Tags: python, r, sorting

I need to replicate the following sorting behavior (found in Python) in R.

Assuming In Python:

```py
l = [(0,0), (1,-1), (-1,0), (-1,-1)]

>>> sorted(l)
[(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (0, 0), (1, -1)]

>>> min(l)
[(-1, -1)]
```

The equivalent data structure in R is:

```
l <- list(c(0,0), c(1,-1), c(-1,0), c(-1,-1))
```

The `sort()` and `sort.list()` methods are not implemented for non-atomic vectors.

In my use-case I can guarantee a list of length 2 vectors, so this works:

```
sorted <- function(list){
  m=matrix(unlist(list), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
  asplit(
    m[order(m[,1],m[,2]),],
    1
  )
}
```

Replicating the behavior of `min` from Python is easy, just relies on the correct function of a `sorted` implementation in R.

`min.list <- function(list) sorted(list)[1]`

Advice on implementing the same behavior as `sorted` is greatly appreciated, and considerations for efficiency are especially welcomed.

Unnecessary for my implementation, but an additional consideration is the `sorted` behavior when the sub-lists varies in length.

```py
>>> sorted([(0,0), (1,1), (0,-1), (0,-1, 0), (0,-1,-1), (0, 0, 0)])

[(0, -1), (0, -1, -1), (0, -1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the issue isn't sorted, per se. Rather, python implements ordering for sequences like this, specifically, lexicographic ordering.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to row bind to a matrix, split by column and use `order()` to get the indices. For ragged data, it's necessary to standardize the lengths first but obviously this step can be skipped for slightly increased efficiency if the data is guaranteed to be of equal length.

```
l <- list(c(0, 0), c(1, 1), c(0, -1), c(0, -1, 0), c(0, -1, -1), c(0, 0, 0))

l[do.call(order, c(asplit(do.call(rbind, lapply(l,
    `length<-`, max(lengths(l)))), 2), na.last = FALSE))]

[[1]]
[1]  0 -1

[[2]]
[1]  0 -1 -1

[[3]]
[1]  0 -1  0

[[4]]
[1] 0 0

[[5]]
[1] 0 0 0

[[6]]
[1] 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can try this way

```
> l <- list(c(0, 0), c(1, 1), c(0, -1), c(0, -1, 0), c(0, -1, -1), c(0, 0, 0))

> l[order(sapply(l, toString))]
[[1]]
[1]  0 -1

[[2]]
[1]  0 -1 -1

[[3]]
[1]  0 -1  0

[[4]]
[1] 0 0

[[5]]
[1] 0 0 0

[[6]]
[1] 1 1
```

Comment: In principle it's unsafe to convert numeric input to strings for sorting as this potentially introduces collation issues.